# C# - Win Forms - WebBrowser Control - Document differs from what is shown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have the problem, that the WebBrowser Control shows something complete different than whats in the code. But I need the document which the control is showing.

In this image you can see for example "principle features not" and "Ausführungs-Historie"
[image]

but the WebBrowser.DocumentText is showing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en" />
    <meta name="generator" content="-Text Replaced-" />
    <meta name="author" content="-Text Replaced-" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="-Text Replaced-" />
    <meta name="robots" content="NOFOLLOW" />
    <title>-Text Replaced-</title>
    <meta name="description" content="-Text Replaced-" />
    <link rel="icon" href="-Text Replaced-" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<frameset rows="-Text Replaced-" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="-Text Replaced-" name="titlebar" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
    <frame src="-Text Replaced-" scrolling='auto' name='mainframe' />
    <noframes>
        <body>-Text Replaced- required a frames supporting browser.</body>
    </noframes>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Some text is replaced with -Text Replaced-. But you can see that these strings definitly are missing: "principle features not" and "Ausführungs-Historie". I don't know why the control shows something complete different than the document text.

Comment: Are you looking for content of iframes?

Comment: No, I only want to access what the Webbrowser shows, see image. I don’t understand how DocumentText can differ to what the browser shows.

Comment: The `DocumentText` is what initially loads into the browser. For example if you have an iframe or if you have some js code which modifies the content `DocumentText` will not show the content of the iframe or it will not show those changes that applied by js.

Comment: And how can I access what’s shown in the Webbrowser Control? That’s the key question :)

Comment: It depends to the requirement, maybe the requirement is not quite clear for me, but to get access to current DOM, (except the iframes contents) you can use `webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml`. Similar for the iframes, for example `webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.Body.OuterHtml`.

Comment: I want to extract the text in the image from the webbrowser control "... principle feature not ..." it's an h2 tag by the way. But I don't find the property where it's in. My webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames Property has 2 entries, but no entry has the informations in it. If I right click on the window and press show sourcecode then the text ist there, but how can I programatically access this source code? Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227271/discussion-between-denis-and-reza-aghaei).